# Firewall rule description

Tags: iptables, ufw

Is it possible to a add rule description in `ufw` or `iptables`, in order to avoid future questions like: "Why did you block this IP?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "iptables", use the module named "comment". Example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -m comment --comment "Masqueraded IP address" -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Gufw (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw) on some computers where I don't want to bother with command-line.

In Gufw you can enter a name for simple and advanced rules that you add. In name of the rule you can enter some text that will remind you, why you entered it. You cannot enter a name for predefined rules, but I guess you don't need description for them.